# Leetcode Target Sum of Recursion with Memoization

Tags: python-3.x

Currently stuck on https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/.

```py
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        count = 0
        @cache
        def dfs(i, cum_sum):
            nonlocal count
            if i >= len(nums):
                if cum_sum == target:
                    count += 1
                return
            dfs(i+1, cum_sum + nums[i])
            dfs(i+1, cum_sum - nums[i])

        dfs(0, 0)
        return count
```

If I remove the @cache, it works, but if I keep it, it gives wrong answer. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem. I was returning None from my dfs function so bunch of None values were being cached.

I fixed it via below code:

```py
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        @cache
        def dfs(i, cum_sum):
            if i >= len(nums):
                return 1 if cum_sum == target else 0
            return dfs(i+1, cum_sum + nums[i]) + dfs(i+1, cum_sum - nums[i])
        return dfs(0, 0)
```